# Gmail API: Unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, gmail-api

I am using GMail API to get code, but I am getting below issue mostly every time:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: 
    sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: 
    sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Can someone please help me on this?

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619030/resolving-javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-sun-security-validator-validatore